# Interactive Flask Prompts

Tags: python, rest, flask, interactive

I'm working on a Flask app to manage a library. One of the problems I'm having has to do with adding new books. In many cases there are "author collisions"; essentially a book with "John Smith" as the author is added and then another book with "John Smith" as an author is added to the database. Is the first book's author "John Smith" the same "John Smith" as the author of the second book?

My solution to this problem is to have modal dialogs where the user is presented with the "author collisions", in the form of the author name, and a list of the books attributed to said author in the database currently. The problem is that I don't know how to implement this. My first idea was to redirect to another page where the user would answer these questions in a new page. The problem is that this requires some seemingly unRESTful contrivances, like saving state data (the rest of the book metadata already entered by the user).

What I'm thinking I should do is implement some sort of "Post method" in `LoanBook(MethodView)` that yields to a succession of modal dialogs (one for each author collision, as books can have multiple authors), submitting only when each collision has been resolved with a 'yes' or 'no'.

Ideally, I would like to be able to halt the Post method (at the point marked: `# ??? yield ???`), wait for the user's response, and then run code based on the response. Then repeat if necessary. I don't know if there is some Flask extension or method that makes this possible, or if this is even possible. Is there another approach I should be doing? Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
class LoanBook(MethodView):
    decorators = [login_required]
    form = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.book = None
        self.form = self.prep_form()

    @permissions_required(Permission.CHECK_OUT_BOOK)
    def get(self):
        return render_template("library/loan_book.html", form=self.form)

    @permissions_required(Permission.CHECK_OUT_BOOK)
    def post(self):        
        if self.form.validate_on_submit():
            if self.form.fill_ISBN.data:
                # User has hit the fill data from ISBN button
                pass
            else:
                try:
                    self.__make_book__()
                    db.session.add(self.book)
                    db.session.commit()
                except InvalidRequestError:
                    db.session.rollback()
                    db.session.flush()
                    flash(FlashMessage.not_saved, FlashMessage.failure)
                else:
                    auths = None
                    if len(loanedBook.authors) > 1:
                        auths = oxford_commatize(
                                [a.full_name() for a in loanedBook.authors]
                            )
                    else:
                        auths = loanedBook.authors[0].full_name()
                    flash(
                        FlashMessage.saved.format(loanedBook.title, auths), 
                        FlashMessage.failure
                    )
                return redirect(url_for("library.main"))
        elif self.form.author_collisions:
            uri_auth = []
            for auth in self.form.author_collisions:
                # ??? yield ???
            self.__make_book__()
            db.session.add(self.book)
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            flash_errors(self.form)
        return render_template("library/loan_book.html", form=self.form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in Flask alone unless, as you say, you get a bit RESTless... But one approach is to pre-save the data and return a page with the first collision with an identifier for the record you are in the process of creating. I would shoehorn in a bit of AJAX or a websocket connection that loads the collisions in another area of the page (a div) when the author's name is entered - if you are hell-bent on complete statelessness :)

I would use websockets (actually, socket.io which is a more functional wrapper for websockets), with a JavaScript event that fires in a request when the user has entered the author's name. The JSON response from the websocket could then be used to populate an area on the page and any matching results could be selected there. Use flask-socketio on the server side; there is a JavaScript example in the docs that should get you started in the browser side.

Flask-SocketIO's docs can be found here:
http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Here is an excellent video showing the basics of this, with a repo for the code used:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5YQbNrFfyw

Comment: The problem is that the collisions aren't detected until the form is submitted. I'm not too familiar with AJAX, is it possible, if given a JSON object matching authors to books, that it could detect collisions when they're entered? How would you go about doing that?

Comment: I would use websockets (actually, socket.io which is a more functional wrapper for websockets), with a JavaScript event that fires in a request when the user has entered the author's name. The JSON response from the websocket could then be used to populate an area on the page and any matching results could be selected there. Use flask-socketio on the server side; there is a JavaScript example in the docs that should get you started in the browser side.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I'd consider this an answer, if you'd just roll the previous comment into your answer, I would select it as such. If this isn't considered "too broad" still :|

Comment: That's done for you :-).  It is a broad question but your use-case is fairly specific.  People seem to prefer "here is what I've tried to do - why doesn't it work?"

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to have much success trying to get user intervention between successive actions on the server side.  An API that can detect these collisions as an asynchronous component of the initial page so that the user can resolve them before submitting to this endpoint might be best.